# Android: Minimizing and resuming a Activity

Tags: android, background, notifications, multitasking, foreground

I am pretty new to Android development .

My problem is a bit tricky one.

I want to develop an application using 2 activities.

1st activity has a button . On clicking the button I want activity 2 to get started as follows:

Activity 2 will come to foreground for 2 seconds and then goes to background for 8 seconds , after which it will again come to foreground for 2 seconds and then again goes to background and the process continues.

Meanwhile both activities should continue their respective tasks.

For ex. We can have a Activity such as Music player which is playing music and another activity named Activity 2 which is downloading some files.

I have tried many things ranging from using Intents to minimizing a activity and displaying notification on notification bar. The problem with notification bar is that it on resuming the activity using notification bar it is always calling OnCreate()  method thus again starting the activity.

I am able to start a activity on button click but don't know how to minimize it and then pop it up in same state .

I am using services in background for timing delays .

Please Help and share your solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved the problem.

The solution is to modify manifest file as :

add to main activity code

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"

android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

add to child activity code

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"

android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

Its works perfectly for my app :)

thank you all for your kind contribution

Answer (score 3):

Maybe u found solution for this issue as u said, but in any case, I would recommend reading some things.. It will help you to better understand that:

- There is no such a thing as minimizing activity ([Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)),
- Activity/Intent [Flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) and [lunching modes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)
- [Tasks and back stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html)
- What is [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) used for,
- What are [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html),
- How to use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Oki.. I made some effort and organize links for you. I know it seems a lot of material, but you don't have to run to read them in next 15min.. Take it easy, read, try, learn. Take this as *advice*, cause once u get used to do things in a wrong way it will be much more difficult to correct them later..

Hope you find it useful.. ;) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

moveTaskToBack(true); moves the whole task to back i.e. it moves both activities to back . Then the problem will be to move the activity to foreground which I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
this.moveTaskToBack(true);
```

I'm not sure if this is what your looking for or not. Heres the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack%28boolean%29) as well!